# Problems reading files in kivy - android

Tags: android, kivy, kivymd, buildozer, filechooser

how to solve the storage access problem on Android to open any type of file.

I have tried putting the permissions in the .spec and the requests in the .py but the filechooser only opens some text or image files. I also tried with plyer but nothing appeared. Thanks for your answers

Comment: What do you consider to be 'the storage access problem'. Using file choosers doesnt require any permission.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. My problem is that I want to develop an application that can graph, but I need to open a specific type of file in .las format and when trying to open the file from the already compiled apk it just doesn't appear

Comment: Why do you keep it that vague? Nobody knows what you do.